# can't override NodePort value in helm configuration for portainer

Tags: kubernetes-helm, portainer, helm3

I am trying to install [portainer with helm](https://github.com/portainer/k8s#deploying-with-helm).

The installation crashes because the port 30777 is already busy on the cluster:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Service "portainer" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 30777: provided port is already allocated
```

So I run the following command to override the port value:

```
helm install -n sandbox-guiops  portainer portainer/portainer --set spec.ports[0].nodePort=40777
```

But I am still getting the same error no matter what.

I am guessing it's because I am not calling the parameter "nodePort" properly, but then again:

```
helm show values portainer/portainer | grep -i port
# Default values for portainer.
    repository: portainer/portainer-ee
  repository: portainer/portainer-ce
  name: portainer-sa-clusteradmin
  # Set the httpNodePort and edgeNodePort only if the type is NodePort
  type: NodePort
  httpPort: 9000
  httpsPort: 9443
  httpNodePort: 30777
  httpsNodePort: 30779
  edgePort: 8000
  edgeNodePort: 30776
```

whether I use "httpNodePort" or anything else, I still get the same error message no matter what.

Comment: The image portainer/portainer is also v1.24 .  You need to use portainer/portainer-ce.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://github.com/portainer/k8s/blob/master/charts/portainer/values.yaml#L35) reference, I think this should be set via

```
--set service.httpNodePort=40777
```

Also its possible to do a `--dry-run --debug` in the helm command to check if the necessary values are populated before trying out an installation.

Comment: Terrific, that makes perfect sense, thank you very much! :)